# How can I make a discord bot check the contents of a message and reply with a different message depending on the author?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I make a discord bot check the contents of a message and reply with a different message depending on the author?
This is my code so far, I found it in a tutorial but it doesn't work. (no error messages for some reason)

```
client.on('message', function (userID, channelID, message) {
    const thisWord = "i'm so cool";
    if(message.content.includes(thisWord)) {
      if(userID === '<@ID>'){
        client.sendMessage({
          to: channelID,
          message: "agreed"
      })
    }}
        else {
          client.sendMessage({
            to: channelID,
            message: "disagreed"
          })
        }
  })
```

Comment: I check userID with `message.author.id`.

Comment: Have a look at the [docs for the message event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message). You only receive `message` so you need to use this

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must be using a later version of DJS. Please update to the newest stable version v12.5.3. Second, the [message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) event only **accepts one parameter** whereas you gave three parameters. Third, if you want to send different replies to different messages, then  you need to handle the message content. That is, split the message content by space and then handle them.
[This](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#basic-arguments) might guide you on working with user input commands.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here looks like you're using the old version of DJS. use the latest one.

This would be the correct usage for discord.js v 12.5.3

```
// the id should be like this '429493473259814923' :)
client.on('message', async message => {
    const thisWord = 'i\'m so cool';
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(thisWord)) {
        if (message.author.id === 'ID') message.reply('disagreed');
        else message.reply('disagreed');
    }
});
```